# Auto re-size container if inner elements too small

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have container, which is re-sizable and contains inner elements `<div>`, which can be placed in any order and I can add them to container any amount when amount of them rising, the become smaller. My goal is when inner divs `height` or `width`, becomes smaller than `100px` then automatically re-size container.

There can be more than one element smaller than `100px`. When container re-sizes, all elements become bigger depending of percents of their `width`.

Problem: when there is more than one small element, they send many events to container, I want to send one request to container to re-size if there is possibility that it is enough to make all element enough size.

I tried to `watch` width, but it sends to many requests.

```
             scope.$watch(function () {
                return element.width();
            }, function (oldval, newval) {
                clearTimeout(containerCtrl.resizedFinished);
                containerCtrl.resizedFinished = setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log("New Value=" + newval);
                    if (newval < 100)
                        scope.resizeContainer(element.width());
                }, 100);
            });
```

Maybe someone can give me any suggestions?
I use Angular, jquery base module, js.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to achieve:

- draggable components should be minimum of 100px wide
- when you drag/drop component into container, all components should shrink, so that they fit inside container
- when components cannot get any smaller, container should grow (with 100px for each added component)

Sounds like you could get the styling done with flexbox in css:

```
.container {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 2px;
    min-width: 500px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.component {
    background-color: grey;
    flex: 0 1 200px;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

That way you do not have to do any watching of components through jQuery.
If the components also should have variable height, and container can have multiple rows, things become trickier. Then you need to be more specific about constraints.

EDIT:
If you cannot use flexbox for IE9, then try:

- add event listener to component being dropped inside container (not on resize of individual components)
- check (read from DOM) how many components are in container
- if (container width - (component width * old number of components)) < 100
- then shrinking is not allowed, so expand container
- else
- loop over each component to shrink them

Comment: You are right what I want to do. not tried your solution, I cannot use flex layout, because need compatibility with IE9.